# Why is it that all of the prices are aligned fine in Chrome and FF but not IE

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

On the following page of one of my client's websites, I have aligned the prices together by the $ sign. It looks great in Chrome and in Firefox yet when I view it in IE the prices are not aligned at all. Any ideas what the situation is here? http://www.polpetteny.com/entrees.html

Comment: looks fine to me can u take a screenshot and what version of IE are you using?

Comment: Can you please remove your code from the website and post it here or in a fiddle? If the website changes or goes down then your question will no longer be of use to anybody

Comment: Sergio Wizenfeld I am using IE9

Comment: @user2649551 I see the problem, but it's not going to be an easy fix. IE renders text differently than Safari or Chrome (both webkit based). You're going to need to figure out either a new format or separate your text into distinct elements so it can be positioned properly.

Comment: @BadKarma I see what you are saying but the issue comes down to the fact that each dish has a different amount of dots. So there is going to be many div tags with specific alignments, right?

Comment: @user2649551 All the solutions to this issue I can think of will be painfully manual to get right in a detailed fashion. If you're looking for a quick fix to the problem, as far as I can see one does not exist

Comment: @BadKarma is what I said correct though?

Comment: @user2649551 Yes that is correct. Your other option would be to use some javascript to serve different HTML to webkit based browsers (safari, chrome) and IE

Comment: Use javascript to check what browser you're in http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_navigator.asp then use that to update the html in certain sections

Comment: @BadKarma yeah unfortunately I am not understanding that. So then the JS tells the CSS which browser I am using to then do the different alignments? I think I may be better off convincing the client to for go the dots and call it a day.

Comment: @user2649551 The fastest solution would be for you to convince your client to ditch the dots and figure out some other way to space out your descriptions and price. If you dont understand what I'm talking about it's probably not worth your time to attempt

Comment: @BadKarma but it is something good to learn. Whether I understand now or understand it later. Can you point me in the direction I would need to go to get a further explanation as to what you are talking about?

Comment: @user2649551 Detect which browser you're in (http://mrbool.com/how-to-detect-different-browsers-and-their-versions-using-javascript/25424) Javascript if/else statements (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) Updating html with javascript (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp)

Comment: @user2649551 Start by reading those websites. If you combine the knowledge in the three of them you can use an if statement to detect which browser the end-user has the website open on then change the html with the dots according to the browser

Comment: @BadKarma thanks but I don't get how the browser detection will tell the proper alignment issues

Comment: @user2649551 It wont tell you the issues. It will allow you to dynamically change the number of dots if the end-user is on a browser showing the wrong spacing

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would change your layout. Relying on text width between different browsers is never a good idea since they all render differently (http://css-tricks.com/font-rendering-differences-firefox-vs-ie-vs-safari/).

If I were you I would separate your menu text into 3 distinct divs (one containing the name & description, one containing the dots and the last containing the price) and float/position them accordingly. That way you could ensure the dots are centered between the price and description and that the price will always be on the far right.

Comment: A table would be easier, considering some of the descriptions are multi-line.

Comment: I feel a table might be easier to separate the different menu items from each other, but with the multi-line problem it would actually be harder. I would make a table w/ each row being a menu item. Make the name/description the full size of the row, then float both the dots and the price to the right.

Comment: @BadKarma so with this option, wrap a div around the table that houses the name/description, then what the dots and price in 2 separate div tags?

Comment: @user2649551 I would avoid the table if you already have a good layout set with your `span` classes. I would separate your menu items into 3 divs (like i stated) and float/position them accordingly. If you always float the name/description to the left and the price to the right (make sure you set it to `vertical-align: bottom;`) then the only thing you will need to adjust dynamically is the spacing of the dots